# Crystal Reports sections problem

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

My Crystal Report is divided like that

1- Report Header

2- Page Header

3- Report details ( section 1 )

4- Report details ( section 2  )

5-Report Footer

My problem lies in the Details ( section 1, and 2 )

I have 2 records appearing in ( section 1 ) and **4 records** in ( section 2 )

That makes my report displays ( section 1 ) in a page and the the rest of the page is blank and ( section 2) appears from the begining of the next page

but I reduced the records to be 2 records appearing in ( section 1 ) and **2 records** in ( section 2 )

They are displayed under each other normally.

What i get is that if the second section fits to be in the blank space left from the upper section it's okay but if the data is larger it starts from a new page,

So what I need is that I want the second section to appear directly under the first section no matter whether it fits or not.

So How can i do that ???

Best Regards.

Baher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the Answer There's an option Known as Keep Object Together if I just Unchecked this option it is solved